# PHP подключение к socks5 прокси через curl

Tags: php, curl, socks5

Пытаюсь подключиться к socks5 прокси через curl, однако получаю ответ *SOCKS : authentication failed*. Попробовал подключиться к прокси-серверу через скрипт Powershell – работает, то есть сам прокси сервер работает, логин и пароль корректны, нужный порт доступен для подключения. Перепробовал множество решений... Не работает только подключение через PHP-скрипт.

Код выглядит так:

```
$proxy = "[login]:[password]@[address]:[port]";
$url = "https://yandex.ru";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
echo $error;
echo $curl_scraped_page;
curl_close($ch);
```

Версия PHP – 5.4, версия cURL – 7.19. К слову, подключение к прокси-серверу по http работало, проблема именно в socks5. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело? Что еще можно предпринять?

Comment: Если там присутствует авторизация, где тогда потеряли `CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH`?

Comment: Пробовал так: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);`. К сожалению, не помогло. Как еще можно попробовать?

Comment: Не хватает еще:  `CURLOPT_USERPWD`. И нужно знать, какая используется авторизация,  ну скорее всего `Basic`.

Comment: На самом деле, код даже в таком виде должен работать. Скорее всего проблема в моем прокси-сервере.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пробуйте это

```
$proxy="ip:port";
$proxy_log_pass="login:pass";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_log_pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
echo $error;
echo $curl_scraped_page;
curl_close($ch);
```